# Force systemd to check status of service after n seconds

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service (for heka) which causes me some headaches.

The problem is that "start" returns successfully even if the heka daemon dies shortly after starting. This is happening if the configuration files are wrong, for example: the process will start, it will verify the configuration and die if it's not happy about what it finds. Systemd returns successfully in this case.

Is there any way to force systemd to check the program status after it is initializing? Maybe to sleep n seconds after the process has started?

This is the script:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Heka event/metric/log collection and routing daemon
    After=network.target auditd.service
    ConditionPathExists=!/etc/heka/hekad_not_to_be_run

    [Service]
    EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/heka
    Type=simple
    PIDFile=/var/run/hekad.pid
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/hekad -config=/etc/heka
    ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
    KillMode=process
    Restart=on-failure
    StandardError=inherit

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
    Alias=heka.service
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain multiple ExecPostStart commands together. And you can run them even if the main ExecStart failed by adding a **-/** ([systemd.service: Type=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=)). Something like this:

```
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/hekad -config=/etc/heka
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 3
ExecStartPost=/bin/kill -0 $MAINPID &>/dev/null
```

This ensures that you still have the `MAINPID` to use when stopping or restarting the service for instance.

Comment: Instead of "kill -0" I used /bin/bash -c "[ ! -z $MAINPID ]"

Answer (score 0):

If there is an easy way to check whether `hekad` is still alive then I would
start the daemon using `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/hekad -config=/etc/heka` and with `ExecStart` run a small script that has a loop that first sleeps X seconds, then checks if the hekad daemon is still running. Breaking the loop only if the `hekad` seems to have stopped.

Comment: I want to control start status even when the daemon is stopped.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't read your answer correctly the first time. But what happens when you want to stop with your script? Systemd will send the kill signals to the process from ExecStart.

Comment: @Cristi the script would have to trap the SIGTERM and kill the real process in function that handles the trap.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExecStartPost` to launch a command or script that sleeps and then runs a check.  If this exits non-zero, the unit is considered a failure.

See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html